# MySQL not finding database/tables through symlink

Tags: centos, mysql, centos7, symlink

In my installation of MySQL the database files are located in `./var/lib/mysql`. I wanted to move one of those databases to another drive, so I followed [instructions to move one database to a different directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14418/different-locations-for-mysql-databases) and copied the data files for the database to a different drive, made a symlink to that directory with the same name as the original database folder. Chowned both the directory recusively and the symlink to mysql, same as the other directories in `./var/lib/mysql`.

When I restarted MySQL, everything ran fine, but the database at issue is missing (Not critical because this is a dry run.) I checked the logs and had these errors:

```
2018-07-28T02:43:59.449437Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace `sf_master/tablename` because it could not be opened.
2018-07-28T02:43:59.449465Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2018-07-28T02:43:59.449474Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './sf_master/tablename.ibd' OS error: 71
```

I set selinux to permissive to see if that was the problem but the errors are the same.

I confirmed that in my.cnf that `symbolic-links=1` and that on the restart I had `innodb_force_recovery = 1`

The data folder looks like:

```
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql mysql         56 Apr 24  2017 auto.cnf
drwxr-x---. 2 mysql mysql       4096 Apr 24  2017 mysql
drwxr-x---. 2 mysql mysql       4096 Dec  6  2017 operators
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql         16 Jul 27 22:33 sf_master -> ./nvme/sf_master
drwxr-x---. 2 mysql mysql       8192 Apr 24  2017 sys
```

NOTE:

I'm posting this problem on serverfault because I think the problem has to do with my understanding of symlinks and the way they are used on directories in linux file systems, or possibly permissions. I'm running a centos 7 server.

UPDATE:

Per Wilson Hauck's request the corrected directory is:

```
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql mysql         56 Apr 24  2017 auto.cnf
drwxr-x---. 2 mysql mysql       4096 Apr 24  2017 mysql
drwxr-x---. 2 mysql mysql       4096 Dec  6  2017 operators
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql         16 Jul 27 22:33 sf_master -> /nvme/sf_master
drwxr-x---. 2 mysql mysql       8192 Apr 24  2017 sys
```

This was really just a very dumb typo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your symlink is wrong.

In `/var/lib/mysql`, the symlink `sf_master -> ./nvme/sf_master` points to `/var/lib/mysql/nvme/sf_master`.  The target of the symlink needs to be a fully-qualified path, not relative to the current directory.  The leading `.` makes it relative.

Comment: I was issuing the commands from the root folder `/` so I mistakenly thought it was relative to root, not to where the symlink was. Thank you. Everything is working right now.

Comment: @AuntJemima Please post the CURRENT data folder content so we can the corrective action you applied for the link to work in your environment.